# Python UCS2 decoding from hex string

Tags: python, string, encoding

I am using python 2.7 and need to decode hex string to unicode string.
In php all simple I make following:

```
$line=hex2bin($line);
$finish=iconv("UCS-2BE","UTF-8",$nline);
```

hex string for example 
    `000A0033002004200430043404300440000A003400200417043D0430043A043E043C0441044204320430000A00350020041C04430437044B043A0430000A00380020041504490435` should be

```
3 Радар
4 Знакомства
5 Музыка
8 Еще
```

How do it in python ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`binascii.unhexlify`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify), then use [`bytes.decode`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) with `utf-16-be` encoding:

```
>>> import binascii

>>> line = '000A0033002004200430043404300440000A003400200417043D0430043A043E043C0441044204320430000A00350020041C04430437044B043A0430000A00380020041504490435'
>>> binascii.unhexlify(line)
b'\x00\n\x003\x00 \x04 \x040\x044\x040\x04@\x00\n\x004\x00 \x04\x17\x04=\x040\x04:\x04>\x04<\x04A\x04B\x042\x040\x00\n\x005\x00 \x04\x1c\x04C\x047\x04K\x04:\x040\x00\n\x008\x00 \x04\x15\x04I\x045'
>>> print(binascii.unhexlify(line).decode('utf-16-be'))

3 Радар
4 Знакомства
5 Музыка
8 Еще
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> line = '000A0033002004200430043404300440000A003400200417043D0430043A043E043C0441044204320430000A00350020041C04430437044B043A0430000A00380020041504490435'
>>> print unicode(line.decode("hex"), "utf-16-be").encode("utf8")

3 Радар
4 Знакомства
5 Музыка
8 Еще
```

Answer (score 1):

Python3 / Without external libs:

```
>>> line = '000A0033002004200430043404300440000A003400200417043D0430043A043E043C0441044204320430000A00350020041C04430437044B043A0430000A00380020041504490435'
>>> output = bytes.fromhex(line).decode('utf-16-be')
>>> print(output)

3 Радар
4 Знакомства
5 Музыка
8 Еще
```