# How to convert string from UCS2 to readable text

Tags: python, c++, arduino

I need to convert the given string from UCS2 to readable text. How can I implement this in Python and C++ Arduino without using third-party modules.

```
st ="041204410451002004210443043F04350440003A00200031003300200413041100200438043D044204350440043D043504420430002C00200031003500300020043C0438043D00200030002004410435043A0020043D04300020043C043E04310438043B044C043D044B043500200420041A00200434043E002000320037002E00300038002E00320032"
```

I found this code, but it does not work as it should. Can you please tell me how to do the correct calculation?

```
def con():
    UCS2ToChar = ''
    res = ""
    arrUCS2 = list("0412")

    if (arrUCS2[1] == '4'):
        if (arrUCS2[2] == '0'): UCS2ToChar = 89
        elif (arrUCS2[2] == '1'): UCS2ToChar = 64
        elif (arrUCS2[2] == '2'): UCS2ToChar = 48
        elif (arrUCS2[2] == '3'): UCS2ToChar = 32
        elif (arrUCS2[2] == '4'): UCS2ToChar = 16
        elif (arrUCS2[2] == '4'): UCS2ToChar = 73

        if (int(arrUCS2[3]) > int('9')):
            UCS2ToChar -= (int(arrUCS2[3]) - 55)
        else:
            UCS2ToChar -= (int(arrUCS2[3]) - int('0'))
        UCS2ToChar = (int(UCS2ToChar))
        res += (chr(UCS2ToChar))
        print(res)
con()
```

If you do this print (ord ('B')) then the code of the letter (which, in theory, is encrypted there) will be different from that obtained using this enumeration.

Comment: The from encoding is USC-2, what's the to encoding UTF-8 or something else ?  Also why is this tagged [c++] ?

Comment: *readable text* is not a real thing. You need to specify what *encoding* you are trying to translate to. This code looks inadequate however whatever the target. A best it translates a tiny subset of UCS-2

Comment: I have specified C++ just for clarification. I need code either in python or arduino.
I also have a character table [link](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ucs2.html). To translate USC2 characters to plain text. But I still don't understand how can I implement this with code. @Richard Critten

Comment: @Sherlock_201 Again plain text is not a well defined concept. Do you mean ASCII? If so then you also need to specify what to do with symbols that exist in UCS-2 and don;t exist in ASCII. How should they be translated.

Comment: That table is the "from" encoding you still have not explained what you mean by _"plain text"_.   All text following some encoding (and there are a lot of them), none are called plain text.  Re: the table in the link - it's short just code a simple map look up with hardcoded values.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that what you have is not actually UCS-2, it's a hex dump. Maybe it's a hex dump of UCS-2 but it's a hex dump none the less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Python UCS2 decoding from hex string - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002691/python-ucs2-decoding-from-hex-string)

```
import binascii

st = "041204410451002004210443043F04350440003A00200031003300200413041100200438043D044204350440043D043504420430002C00200031003500300020043C0438043D00200030002004410435043A0020043D04300020043C043E04310438043B044C043D044B043500200420041A00200434043E002000320037002E00300038002E00320032"

text = binascii.unhexlify(st).decode('utf-16-be')

print(text)
```

or

```
import codecs

st = "041204410451002004210443043F04350440003A00200031003300200413041100200438043D044204350440043D043504420430002C00200031003500300020043C0438043D00200030002004410435043A0020043D04300020043C043E04310438043B044C043D044B043500200420041A00200434043E002000320037002E00300038002E00320032"

text = codecs.decode(st, 'hex').decode('utf-16-be') 

print(text)
```

Result:

```
Всё Супер: 13 ГБ интернета, 150 мин 0 сек на мобильные РК до 27.08.22
```

[binascii](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) and [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) are standard modules preinstalled with Python.